# How can I implement a Database based on a Web Service?

Tags: xml, database, oracle, web-services, soap

I have access to a Soap Web Service to which data providers upload XML data on a monthly basis.  I would like to implement an Oracle database connected to this Web Service. Although I am confused on how to do this task, I assume the steps are the following:

1. Install Oracle.
2. Create all tables (based on XML tags), which is a little confusing because some tags have child tags.
3. Connect my database to the Web service (I have no idea how to do so)
4. Set a way to update my database manually when I know it is time to do so.

PS: I am new to databases and web services. Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a recommandation (or even a warning): if you have never worked with Oracle I don't recommend to start with Oracle database as things are generally much more complex for a beginner compared to PostgreSQL or MySQL/MariaDB or even SQL Server (on Windows).

If you still want to do this with Oracle database, try to:

1. install Oracle XE 18c: Express Edition can do many things but is much easier to install than Oracle Entreprise Edition
2. install APEX in the database
3. install ORDS in the database

You have all the general links on Oracle web site https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe/faq.html#not_incl ... but it is likely easier to adapt following steps to Oracle XE https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the process if I chose Postgresql instead of Oracle?

Comment: To install  PostgreSQL on Linux I recommend to use the package manager of your Linux distribution. I am not sure there is free software for using SOAP with PostgreSQL. But you can install easily PostgREST: http://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/tutorials/tut0.html